# Type of expression is ambigous without more context

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

Im trying to make `dateAndResultsDictionary` and empty array of dictionaries, but i'm getting this error. What am i doing wrong?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement is syntactically incorrect. A dictionary can't hold more than one type of key or value so a type declaration like this:

```
[String: [Int], String: String]
```

is illegal. NB `[Int]` and `Array<Int>` are semantically identical.

If you want to hold more than one kind of thing, probably the best way is to use an enum:

```
 enum DictionaryContent 
 {
     case string(String)
     case intArray([Int])
 }

 var dateAndResultDictionary = [[String: DictionaryContent]]()
```